# If $X,Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ are not measure zero sets, how can I show that $X\times Y\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a measure zero set too?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, differential-geometry

If $X,Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ are not measure zero sets, how can I show  that $X\times Y\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a measure zero set too?

or (the following is an easy case)

If $X\subset\mathbb{R}$ is not a measure zero set, how can I show that $X\times\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a measure zero set too?

How can I show the assertion by using the definition of measure zero (as follows)?

(A subset $Z\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a mesuare zero set if $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists$ countable open intervals $I_1, I_2, \cdots$ 
s. t. $Z\subset \cup_k I_k$ and $\sum_{k}length[I_k]<\varepsilon$).

Comment: The following is my thought and the strategy.
Suppose $X\times Y$ is a measure zero set. 
Then, there exist countable open interbals $I_1,I_2,\ldots $ and 
$J_1,J_2,\ldots $ such that $X\times Y \subset \cup_kI_k \times I_k$ 
and $\sum_k length[I_k\times J_k]<\varepsilon$. Then, $\sum_k length[I_k]\times length[J_k] <\varepsilon$.

But I do not have ideas for the next.

Comment: Your definition of "measure zero set" makes sense for subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  What is your definition for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: A subset $X\times Y\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a measure zero set if 
$\forall \varepsilon$, $\exists$ countable open interbals $I_1, I_2,\ldots$ and $J_1,J_2,\ldots$ s. t.  $X\times Y\subset \cup_k I_k\times J_k$ 
and $\sum_k length[I_k] length[J_k]< \varepsilon$.

Comment: By using the definition above, how we show the assertion?

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are *Borel measurable sets* and have nonzero measure, then $X \times Y$ has nonzero measure.

Take any set $X$ of nonzero measure and now ask yourself what sets $Y$ behave nicely.

Of course if $Y$ is an interval your approach gives you the desired result. Suppose that $\lambda(X \times Y) = 0$ and choose intervals $I_k, J_k$ such that $$X \times Y \subset \bigcup_k I_k \times J_k$$ where the latter union is disjoint and it holds that: $\sum \lambda(I_k \times J_k) \le \epsilon.$

Without loss of generality you can take all $J_k = Y$ and you would get $\lambda(X)  \le \sum \lambda(I_k) \le \epsilon / \lambda(Y).$ So since $Y$ has nonzero measure you would get that $X$ has zero measure. This is a contradiction.

Now you can build the class of sets that behave nicely, i.e the class $\mathcal{M}$ of all the sets $Y$ such that if $X \times Y$ has measure zero than $Y$ must have measure zero: $$\mathcal{M} = \{ Y \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ measurable, s.t. either } \lambda(Y) = 0 \text{ or } \lambda(X \times Y) > 0\}$$

This class is closed under countable monotone unions and intersections and contains intervals. Hence it is a monotone class which contains intervals (which in turn form a $\pi-$system). Hence by the monotone class theorem it contains all Borel sets on the real line.

Comment: Please give more details. Are you claiming to have an actual proof, or just an idea that might work? What is the exact statement that you claim to have proved?

Comment: Does "$X$ and $Y$ have nonzero measure" mean that they are ***measurable*** sets of positive measure? As far as I know, the OP is only assuming that they are not measure zero sets, i.e., they could be nonmeasurable sets.

Comment: @bof you are perfectly right. I assume the sets are Borel measurable. I have two remarks to make. First the question does not ask explicitly for the non Borel case and in my opinion the level of the question does not imply such a generality. In any case the result is extended to Lebesgue measurable sets (since they differ from a Borel only by a nullset). If it turns out that we are actually speaking of outer measures I will take back or possibly change my answer.

Comment: What's the answer for arbitrary sets? Can the product of two non-measurable sets be a nullset??

Comment: @bof $\lambda(X \times Y) = \lambda(X) \cdot \lambda(Y).$ This holds also for the outer measure. But the proof of this typically involves looking at sections. Here we are asked to *use the definition* of (outer) measure. I couldn't come up with anything better then I wrote.

Answer (score -3):

If $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{p+q}\quad$and$\quad mE=0$then $mE_x=0$a.e. in  $\mathbb{R}^p$
where$ E_x=\{y:y\in\mathbb{R}^p (x,y)\in E\}$

Comment: How can I show the assertion by using the definition of measure zero (written above )?

Comment: That is not really understandable text to me.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand it.  
How can I show the assertion by using the definition of measure zero (written above )?